# d3js world map - highlighting countries that have the same startTime

Tags: d3.js

I am have some data that looks something like this -- a list of countries with start/end timestamps for a set of promotions.

I made a gannt chart to review the data - but as the promotions start on the same day, but a few hours apart form each other - its not as useful. I am wondering if I could adapt a worldmap - that is powered by the data -- and the countries are colorcoded the same on the statTime they start at. Having a legend that reflects this

```
[red] 10:00
[blue] 11:00
[orange] 12:00
```

anything like this?

```
  var data = [
    {
      "label": "Argentina",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-14T15:20:00Z'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-05-30T03:59:00Z')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Bolivia",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time":Date.parse('2020-01-17T03:24:00'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-06-28T03:24:00')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Brazil",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-01-20T03:24:00'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-02-17T03:24:00')}
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Canada",
      "isIncluded": true,
      "times": [
        {"text": "", "starting_time": Date.parse('2020-02-20T03:24:00'), "ending_time": Date.parse('2020-04-20T03:24:00')}
      ]
    }
]
```

[image]
http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f

Comment: do you have a question other than "is this possible?"  it is possible.  You'll want to normalize the times to reflect the resolution in the legend, i.e., hours rather than minutes.

Comment: I am trying to conceptualise this -- I've not seen a world map chart used in this way - is there a clean d3map chart around -- could I use something like this current example to map the countries in my array -- and colorize them according to the start hour that they began?

Comment: In the block you cite in your question, there is a `color` function which maps discrete `population` data values as the domain array to the range array of color values.  You can use the same function, replacing the population values with time values.  A critical step, as i mentioned, is to make sure your time domain is stratified into discrete values (i.e., hours) in both your scaling (i.e., color) function and your data.  IOW, `3:00` wont match `3:24` so change `3:24` (and all other timestamps between `3:00` and `3:59` to `3:00` or make them all just `3`.

Comment: you have an example of this?

Comment: I probably don't have a simple example, but there are many many examples of this online. The type of viz you are attempting is called a "choropleth" (meaning "multitude of regions").  a search for "d3 choropleth how to" yields many blocks, tutorials, and videos about how to construct them.  In short, you obtain widlely available geo data, merge your data with it, choose and implement color scales, and voila.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/aLh9d51t/1/  - I've tried to create a js fiddle - but its broken